# Why is this not a bug in qmail?

Tags: c, unix, qmail

I was reading DJB's ["Some thoughts on security after ten years of Qmail 1.0"](http://cr.yp.to/qmail/qmailsec-20071101.pdf) and he listed this function for moving a file descriptor:

```
int fd_move(to,from)
int to;
int from;
{
  if (to == from) return 0;
  if (fd_copy(to,from) == -1) return -1;
  close(from);
  return 0;
}
```

It occurred to me that this code does not check the return value of close, so I read the man page for close(2), and it seems it *can* fail with `EINTR`, in which case the appropriate behavior would seem to be to call close again with the same argument.

Since this code was written by someone with far more experience than I in both C and UNIX, and additionally has stood unchanged in qmail for over a decade, I assume there must be some nuance that I'm missing that makes this code correct.  Can anyone explain that nuance to me?

Comment: Maybe "from" is checked before the function fd_mode is called

Comment: In what way could "from" be checked such that an EINTR return from close(2) could be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a file descriptor is dup'd, as it is in the `fd_copy` or `dup2` function, you will end up with more than one file descriptor referring to the same thing (i.e. the same `struct file` in the kernel).  Closing one of them will simply decrement its reference count.  No operation is performed on the underlying object unless it is the *last* close.  As a result, conditions such as `EINTR` and `EIO` are not possible.

Comment: But are signals blocked while in the close(2) system call?  If not, a signal could be delivered at any point, between any two instructions--even between the decrement of a reference count and the return from the syscall, right?

Comment: If the signal arrives while the thread is in a system call, the signal will be pending until either the system call goes into an interruptible sleep or the system call returns.  It is possible for the system call to be preempted involuntarily by another thread/interrupt handler, but when the interrupted thread resumes it will continue where it left off in the system call and will not check for pending signals at that point.  A system call cannot be aborted at an arbitrary instruction; there's no telling what state that might leave the thread in.

Comment: that behavior may be the case on Linux, but it cannot be portably relied upon without using SA_RESTART with sigaction.

Answer (score 2):

I've got two answers:

1. He was trying to make a point about factoring out common code and often such examples omit error checking for brevity and clarity.
2. close(2) may return EINTER, but does it in practice, and if so what would you reasonably do? Retry once? Retry until success? What if you get EIO? That could mean almost anything, so you really have no reasonable recourse except logging it and moving on. If you retry after an EIO, you might get EBADF, then what? Assume that the descriptor is closed and move on?

Every system call can return EINTR, escpecially one that blocks like read(2) waiting on a slow human. This is a more likely scenario and a good "get input from terminal" routine will indeed check for this. That also means that write(2) can fail, even when writing a log file. Do you try to log the error that the logger generated or should you just give up?

Comment: I just took a quick look at the linux2.6/fs/open.c kernel code and while `man 2 close` has boilerplate EINTR return as do all system calls, it looks like sys_close may only every return EBADF.

Comment: "if so what would you reasonably do?" retry until success, usually (having first handled the signal if appropriate). If you get EIO or EBADF, you give up, because those are permanent failures to do with the state of the file descriptor. EINTR is a temporary failure to do with the state of the process/thread. At least, it is if your program is otherwise correct. If your call to `close` *results* in a signal being sent to your process, something is badly wrong.

Comment: @Steve, retrying until success could result in the program hanging in an infinite loop. It's better just to assume it closed successfully (leaving the descriptor open, in the unlikely event it failed).

Comment: @msw, a third option is that the author assumed that any signal handler will be installed using "sigaction" with the "SA_RESTART" flag (restart interrupted system calls) specified.

Comment: @msw The copied code is verbatim from qmail 1.03, so it's not just example code.

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan: That's interesting.  I checked my manpage for sigaction, though, and SA_RESTART doesn't seem to apply to the close(2) syscall.  It also doesn't show up in the qmail source, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: @jemfinch, the SA_RESTART flag applies to any system call that can fail with EINTR due to being interrupted by a signal. It does not necessarily need to be mentioned explicitly in the man page of the system function that can fail for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that his function is used only in an application (or a part of one) which has done something to ensure that the call will not be interrupted by a signal. If you aren't going to do anything important with signals, then you don't have to be responsive to them, and it might make sense to mask them all out, rather than wrap every single blocking system call in an EINTR retry. Except of course the ones that will kill you, so SIGKILL and frequently SIGPIPE if you handle it by quitting, along with SIGSEGV and similar fatal errors which will in any case never be delivered to a correct user-space app.

Anyway, if all he's talking about is security, then quite possibly he doesn't have to retry `close`. If close failed with EIO, then he would not be able to retry it, it would be a permanent failure. Therefore, it is not necessary for the correctness of his program that `close` succeeds. It may well be that it is not necessary for the correctness of his program that `close` be retried on EINTR, either.

Usually you want your program to make a best effort to succeed, and that means retrying on EINTR. But this is a separate concern from security. If your program is designed so that some function failing for any reason isn't a security flaw, then in particular the fact that it *happens* to have failed EINTR, rather than for a permanent reason, isn't a flaw. DJB has been known to be fairly opinionated, so I would not be at all surprised if he has proved some reason why he doesn't *need* to retry, and therefore doesn't bother, even if doing so would allow his program to succeed in flushing the handle in certain situations where maybe it currently fails (like being explicitly sent a harmless signal with `kill` by the user at a crucial moment).

Edit: it occurs to me that retrying on EINTR could potentially itself be a security flaw under certain conditions. It introduces a new behaviour to that section of code: it can loop indefinitely in response to a signal flood, where previously it would make one attempt to `close` and then return. I don't know for sure that this would cause qmail any problems (after all, `close` itself makes no guarantees how soon it will return). But if giving up after one attempt does make the code easier to analyse then it could plausibly be a smart move. Or not.

You might think that retrying prevents a DoS flaw, where a signal causes a spurious failure. But retrying allows another (more difficult) DoS flaw, where a signal flood causes an indefinite stall. In terms of binary "can this app be DoSed?", which is the kind of absolute security question DJB was interested in when he wrote qmail and djbdns, it makes no difference. If something can happen once, then normally that means it can happen many times.

Answer (score 0):

Only broken unices ever return `EINTR` without you explicitly asking for it. The sane semantics for `signal()` enable restartable system calls ("BSD style"). When building a program on a system with the sysv semantics (interrupting signals), you should always replace calls to `signal()` with calls to `bsd_signal()`, which you can define yourself in terms of `sigaction()` if it doesn't exist.

It's further worth noting that **no** systems will return `EINTR` on signal receipt unless you have installed signal handlers. If the default action is left in place, or if the signal is set to no action, it's impossible for system calls to be interrupted.